# CMD prompt closes right on bat open

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Quite simple batch question, I need to create a bat file which'll open cmd and in there display the date, a persons windows username and change the color scheme.

So far I got this

```
@echo off

prompt $t $$
echo %DATE%
color f0
```

This opens a cmd prompt but then closes it right after so I added `PAUSE` to the end.

After adding `PAUSE` the cmd window became unuseable (Press any key to continue... and then it'd close).
I just want to be able to actually use the cmd window like a normal command prompt but with my messages above added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me as if you're looking to do something a little more like this:

```cmd
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /T:F0 /K "Prompt $T $$& Echo %%DATE%%"
```

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
@echo off

prompt $t $$
echo %DATE%
color f0
@pause
```

Output:

```
Fri 12/04/2020
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I can't use the created prompt to issue commands like any other normal cmd

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would append `pause >nul` to the file. This will run the `pause` command to prevent the window from closing until it gets user input, and the `>nul` part just hides the output of the `pause` command.